# How to display an jpeg image on xerver using x11?

Tags: image, x11, xserver

I want to display a jpeg image in xserver using x11. I downloaded imagemagick, but dont' know how to do it.

I want to display that image as a child window of another window. Is there any xlib code to display a image on window?

Comment: you've completely changed your question.

Answer (score 9):

You can use 'display' to display images on screen. Your question is vague, it lacks context.

http://www.imagemagick.org/www/display.html

Answer (score 1):

xview should be installed on every *nix system...